# How to declare labels in loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, label

How to automate creating objects in a loop? Why doesn't this code work?

```
String strLbl[] = {"Model","Weight","Length","Age","Number of keys"};
JLabel lbl[] = new JLabel[5];

for (int i=0;i<strLbl.length;i++){
    JLabel lbl[i] = new JLabel(strLbl[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type declaration isnt allowed for an array element assignment:

```
JLabel lbl[i] = new JLabel(strLbl[i]);
```

should be

```
lbl[i] = new JLabel(strLbl[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, in Java 8:

```
JLabel lbl[] = Arrays.stream(strLbl).map(s -> new JLabel(s)).toArray();
```